# Unable to remove empty parameters in url using context path in Location tag in apache http server

Tags: mod-rewrite, location, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

Unable to remove empty parameters in url using context path in Location tag in apache http server
Without context path setting, empty parameters are being removed correctly as expected,

Below is the example with context path, where empty parameters are not removed (Problem statement)

```
<Location /reports/>
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    ProxyPass http://1.2.3.4:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://1.2.3.4:3000/
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?[^=]+=(?:&(.*))?$
    RewriteRule ^/reports$ /reports/?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L]
</Location>
```

Below is the example without context path, where empty parameters are removed as expected (But the final solution needs to work with a context path)

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass http://1.2.3.4:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://1.2.3.4:3000/
    RewriteEngine On
    AllowOverride All
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?[^=]+=(?:&(.*))?$
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L]
</Location>
```

How do I remove the empty parameters from the URL with the context path setting in the location?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <Location /reports/>
>     :
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteBase /
>     : 
>     RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?[^=]+=(?:&(.*))?$
>     RewriteRule ^/reports$ /reports/?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L]
> </Location>
> ```

There are several issues here...

- Your `<Location>` block matches `/reports/` (with a trailing slash), but your `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^/reports$` omits the trailing slash, so it will never match.
- `<Location>` blocks are merged very late and in this context the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the absolute filesystem path, not the root-relative URL-path.

  So in order to match the request, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* should be like `/reports/$` instead to allow for the absolute filesystem path, eg. `/path/to/document-root/reports/`. In other words:

  ```
   RewriteRule /reports/$ /reports/?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L]
  ```

  Or, omit the path component of the `RewriteRule` *pattern* altogether (eg. simply `^`), unless you must only match `/reports/` and not `/reports/<anything>`.
- HOWEVER, you shouldn't use mod_rewrite directives inside a `<Location>` block to begin with. From the [Apache 2.4 docs on the `RewriteRule` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

  > Although rewrite rules are syntactically permitted in `<Location>` and `<Files>` sections (including their regular expression counterparts), **this should never be necessary and is unsupported**. A likely feature to break in these contexts is relative substitutions.
- The `RewriteBase` directive is not being used here. (But it is not supported/not required outside of a *directory* context.)

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* and the `<Location>` directive are performing the same check. Move these mod_rewrite directives outside of the `<Location>` container and have them directly in the `<VirtualHost>` container (or *server* context). For example:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?[^=]+=(?:&(.*))?$
RewriteRule ^/reports/$ /reports/?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L]

<Location /reports/>
    ProxyPass http://1.2.3.4:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://1.2.3.4:3000/
</Location>
```

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite. I tried this configuration and the same problem persists. When I access the reports url using the context path, /reports/, with multiple parameters (including one blank one), the empty parameters are not removed in the url. The empty parameters are only removed when I specify the location tag without any context path.

Comment: @AmitSanghavi Where exactly are you putting these directives?

Comment: @AmitSanghavi Also please give an example of the URL (with empty parameters) you are requesting.